# how do synced-cron job executes every 2 hour in a day

Tags: meteor, cron

How do synced-cron job executes every 2 hour in a day. I'm using `percolate:synced-cron` package in meteor.
Here is my server code:

```
SyncedCron.add({
    name: 'Cron job will start on',
    schedule: function(parser) {
        // parser is a later.parse object
        return parser.text('every 2 hour');
    },
    job: function() {
        FetchDailyBasisData();
    }
});

Meteor.startup(function () {
    SyncedCron.start();
});
```

It suppose to work but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

It should be `return parser.text('every 2 hours');`
 Notice the *s* in hours.

In the [docs](http://bunkat.github.io/later/parsers.html#overview), the following periods are defined :

> Periods
>   s, sec, seconds, m, min, minutes, h, hours, day, day of the month, day instance, day of the week, day of the year, week, week of the year, month, year